# Partitioning non-partitioned table in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, partitioning

I have a table which in my opinion will benefit from partitioning:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[my_table](
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[external_id] [int] NOT NULL,
[amount] [money] NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC));
```

There are just few different `external_id` and thousands of records for each of them.
SSMS Create Partition Wizard generates a script that I don't completely understand. After creating partition function and partition schema,
--it drops Primary Key,
--then creates Primary Key again on `id`, this time as non-clustered,
--then creates clustered index on `external_id` on newly created partition schema,
--and finally it drops the clustered index created on previous step.

Everything except last step seems clear, but I cannot get why it has to drop the clustered index. Should I remove the last step from the batch?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are going for Partitioning , is there any query you are looking for Performance ?

Comment: @SQL- My main concern is not performance of `select`, but merging with new data. I only select 1 (using top) row for a given `external_id`, work with it and delete it. When no records found, I insert another couple of thousands records for this `external_id`. Generating required data in advance and just switching to a new partition seems to work a way faster than thousands (some times millions) `INSERT`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes sense.

The partition key is going to be the external id, so the clustered index must include that.

It preserves the primary key in a non-clustered index - since it's on ID not external_id

It created the clustered index on external_id to physically move the data into the partition scheme.

It drops the clustered index since it only used it to move the data - it was not a previously specified index.

There are a number of alternatives, assuming you always know the external_id, then you could choose to create the clustered index as (id,external_id) - the partition schema / function field used for the table must be within the clustered index on the partition schema.

Performance wise, this is not going to be a huge boost, the use of it is more that you can drop an entire external_id trivially, instead of a large delete transaction.

Comment: Would it be bad if I left clustered index on `external_id`? I also was thinking about creating a clustered index on (`external_id,id`) rather than  index on (`id,external_id`) as you proposed. I'm not sure if it makes sense though...

Comment: not bad per se, but not providing you any real benefit since the index is then the same as the partitioning, so the index provides no extra benefits. If you search on ID as well as External_ID, then put it in the CL IX if you keep  it

Comment: (usual caveats apply, theory is one thing, performance testing with real results is another)